# IIS React Deployment for Sub Url/Domain 504

Tags: reactjs, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to access the react application that is being deployed in IIS with a `URL Rewrite` with following settings:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[image]

It gaves me an error `504 Gateway Timeout` when I am trying to access the `https://xxxx.com/grt`.  Also I when looking into the network it seems that it tries to get the `bundle.js` from `https://xxxx.com/` which receives `404 Not Found` instead of `https://xxxx.com/grt/bundle.js` which is the correct path.  Did I setup the rewrite url for `react` application configuration correctly? or did I missed something along the way?

Comment: Try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: I see, okay will try this one and hopefully fix this issue right away.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: hi @samwu, we have the logs but the error shows `500.52` which is rewrite module error. I tried my best to configure the IIS but no luck.  Do you have any suggestions why is this happening?

Comment: The Failed Request Tracing log file will clearly tell you the exact error message, or you can directly tell me the URL you want to redirect, i will make demo for you.